Old TV series about red people
About 20 years ago I have watched an old TV series made in the USA (made between 60s-80s).
It had a main protagonist (detective maybe), and he was either escaping or hunting the aliens. The aliens actually looked like people (identical) and were in some way mysterious men in black (or gray smoking with hat). Once the protagonist killed them, they would start to glow completely red and disappear.
What is the name of the TV Series? 

The Invaders with Roy Thinnes

The existence of the Invaders could not be documented by killing one and examining the body: when they died, their bodies would glow red and disintegrate along with their clothes and anything else they were touching, leaving little more than traces of black ash.




